# Nextjs - multer - TypeError: Cannot read property 'transfer-encoding' of undefined

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, multer, cloudinary

I am new to Nextjs and trying to upload file via multer and getting the error TypeError: Cannot read property 'transfer-encoding' of undefined. The route is protected so have to add auth middleware, which is working fine, but I am unable to figure out how to use multer in this situation.

Here is the code.

multer.js

```
import multer from "multer";
import path from "path";

// Multer config
export default multer({
  storage: multer.diskStorage({}),
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    let ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
    if (ext !== ".jpg" && ext !== ".jpeg" && ext !== ".png") {
      cb(new Error("File type is not supported"), false);
      return;
    }
    cb(null, true);
  },
});
```

cloudinary.js

```
import cloudinary from "cloudinary";

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
});
export default cloudinary;
```

requireLogin.js (auth middleware)

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

const requireLogin = (fn) => {
  return (req, res) => {
    const { authorization } = req.headers;
    if (!authorization) {
      return res.status(403).json({ error: "Restricted access" });
    }
    try {
      const decode = jwt.verify(authorization, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
      req.user = decode;
      return fn(req, res);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: "Something went wrong" });
    }
  };
};

export default requireLogin;
```

pages/api/products.js

```
import Product from "../../models/Product";
import User from "../../models/User";
import initDB from "../../utils/db";
import requireLogin from "../../utils/requireLogin";
import cloudinary from "../../utils/cloudinary";
import upload from "../../utils/multer";

initDB();

export default async (req, res) => {

  const createProduct = requireLogin((request, response) => {
    upload.single("image")(async (req, {}, err) => {
      try {
        let user = await User.findById(req.user._id);
        if (user.role !== "admin") {
          return response.status(403).json({ error: "You must be an admin to add product" });
        }

        const result = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.file.path);
        req.body.image = result.secure_url;
        req.body.cloudinary_id = result.public_id;

        const product = new Product({
          name,
          price,
          description,
          image: req.body.image,
          cloudinary_id: req.body.cloudinary_id,
        });

        await product.save();
        response.json(product);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  });

  switch (req.method) {
    case "POST":
      return createProduct(req, res);    
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Its solved. I didn't know that I have to set bodyParser to false

pages/api/products.js

```
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

export default // rest of the code
```